# MYSQL Cartesian product instead of related rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Using the following database with 3 tables in `MySQL` and the following query the result is always the cartesian product. Instead i want to get the direct related rows like 1 record in `a`, 2 records in `b` and `c` resulting in two rows as result because the foreign key relates many rows in `b` and `c` to ONE in `a`.

[image]

**Used query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.a as tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN test.b tableB ON tableB.id_a = tableA.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN test.c tableC ON tableC.id_a = tableA.id;
```

**And finally the result of the query:**
[image]

What am I doing wrong, i only would expect to results, also the foreign key constraint seems to be correct?

This is the desired result:

[image]

Comment: What result did you expect? I mean - how would the expected two rows look like?

Comment: You really can't join to multiple tables sharing a "plural" relation to the same table... at least not without some serious headaches and convoluted queries. You can look at it as that the second join is effectively joining to the results of the first join.

Comment: you're joining one-to-many relationships which is why you have a partial cartesian product

Comment: I added the desired result, how can i query this as result?

Comment: Also the following result returns the same: SELECT * FROM test.a as tableA, test.b as tableB, test.c as tableC where tableC.id_a = tableB.id_a

Comment: So you pick the rows, where the primary keys of tables b and c are equal? You could define that in the WHERE clause (`WHERE tableB.id = tableC.id`) or in the ON clause of table c join (`ON tableC.id_a = tableA.id AND tableC.id = tableB.id`). But it doesn't seam reasonable. Is there any logical relation between tableB.id and tableC.id?

Comment: Thanks, there is a relation between b.id and c.id, because the records are inserted in the same order so its id (autoincrment) is each time equal. But its better to link that logically by relating each pair of rows from b and c by some sort of extra id field because relying on equal autoincrement could go wrong in some ways i guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting a cartesian product. You're getting exactly what you ask for: the result of 2 outer joins.

You might not realize it yet, but you're expecting the 2 joins to merge transversaly together to give you 2 records only, magically knowing that id of table B should map to id of table C. This is actually feasible the way you'd like but it's way more complicate that you'd think (see pivoting in mysql for more information - but it's just an example of how to do it)

Rather, I'll show you your problem.

1. You're asking for A outer join B. Result is 2 records, because it seems there are 2 records in table B with id_a = 2. The intermediate resultset count is 2.
2. You're asking for A outer join C. Similarly, result is 2 records, because it seems there are also 2 records in table C with id_a = 2. The intermediate resultset count is 2.

But you're not asking mysql anything about how to organize/join the these 2 intermediate resultsets. Therefore, mysql is crossing them together, which may have lead you originally to think it's a cartesian product, and displays the final result that you observed. Total rows = 4, 2 from 1st resultset, times 2, from 2nd resultset.

A cartesian product would have included every records of all 3 tables crossed with each other: a times b times c.

So, in conclusion, you could "hack" the query to show as you want, by establishing a joining criteria between C and B. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.a as tableA
LEFT JOIN test.b tableB ON tableB.id_a = tableA.id
LEFT JOIN test.c tableC ON tableC.id_a = tableA.id AND tableC.id = tableB.id
;
```

But really it's a hack, you probably need to define a better criteria than a technical id identity.

Comment: I also looks like cartesian product, because there is only one row in table a and all rows from tables b and c are related to it.

Comment: True, that indeed does a result of 4 by coincidence in that case.

Comment: Actually, he'd get the same thing with inner joins.

Comment: That is also true :-) But it goes beyond the scope of this post :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i understand my problem no of the missing logical relation between b and c records linking each other. Your join proposal by id would do for the first because the ids are always equal but i definitely have to improve the database structure by adding a logical link between a and b e.g. some sort of relation_id